# How can I use image_dataset_from_directory with autoencoder?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

- I have a big dataset which I want to use in order to train my convolutional autoencoder.
- Like every autoencoder, my convolutional autoencoder needs to be trained with: x=y as the input (same `x_train` and `x_test` in the X and Y parameters)

for example:

```
autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=50,
                batch_size=256,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

1. How can I use `image_dataset_from_directory` to fit my autoencoder ?
2. How can I set `image_dataset_from_directory` with same x and y parmeters (as I mentioned above) ?

Comment: Here is a very good answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69813100/5440823

Answer (score 1):

as the link posted by "dogvarog" provided the full example, I just want to add my two cents to simplify the answer and also add the train/validate split method when Dataset encountered:

```
df_auto_train = df_train.map(lambda x, y: (x, x))
X_auto_train = df_auto_train.take(int(0.9*len(df_auto_train)))
X_auto_validate = df_auto_train.skip(int(0.9*len(df_auto_train)))
```

1. Just use the "map" function to change the labels to images.
2. if you want to use train + validation, it is impossible to use validation_split in Dataset, instead, using "take" and "split".

Answer (score -1):

You can get the result you want by using the ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory. Documentation is [here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) If you set the class_mode = "input" the generator y output is identical to the x input. The documentation specifically states this is useful for auto encoders.

Comment: The question specifically asked how it can be done using, image_dataset_from_directory

Comment: And the reason we're asking about not using **ImageDataGenerator** is because [*"`tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` is not recommended for new code."*](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator)